# Twillio Chat Module error TS1086 An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context

Tags: angular, npm, twilio, angular-cli

I have an angular project which is version controlled. Its working fine on a windows machine.
But when i pulled the changes to my Ubuntu 19 machine i always get a twillio chat module error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/channel.d.ts(122,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/channel.d.ts(123,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/channel.d.ts(124,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/channel.d.ts(125,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/channel.d.ts(126,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/channel.d.ts(127,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/channel.d.ts(128,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/channel.d.ts(129,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/channel.d.ts(130,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/channel.d.ts(131,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/channel.d.ts(132,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/channel.d.ts(133,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/client.d.ts(130,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/client.d.ts(131,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/client.d.ts(132,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/configuration.d.ts(13,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/configuration.d.ts(14,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/configuration.d.ts(15,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/configuration.d.ts(16,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/configuration.d.ts(17,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/configuration.d.ts(18,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/media.d.ts(23,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/media.d.ts(24,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/media.d.ts(25,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/media.d.ts(26,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/member.d.ts(53,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/member.d.ts(54,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/member.d.ts(55,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/member.d.ts(56,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/member.d.ts(57,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/member.d.ts(58,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/member.d.ts(59,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/member.d.ts(60,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/member.d.ts(61,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/member.d.ts(62,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/message.d.ts(48,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/message.d.ts(49,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/message.d.ts(50,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/message.d.ts(51,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/message.d.ts(52,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/message.d.ts(53,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/message.d.ts(54,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/message.d.ts(55,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/message.d.ts(56,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/message.d.ts(57,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/message.d.ts(58,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/restpaginator.d.ts(12,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/restpaginator.d.ts(13,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/restpaginator.d.ts(14,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/services/typingindicator.d.ts(21,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/session.d.ts(30,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/session.d.ts(31,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/user.d.ts(50,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/user.d.ts(51,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/user.d.ts(52,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/user.d.ts(53,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/user.d.ts(54,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/user.d.ts(55,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/user.d.ts(56,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/user.d.ts(57,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/twilio-chat/lib/util/deferred.d.ts(7,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
```

I tried to delete the node_module folder and use `npm install` but it stayed the same

I also upgrade the version of angular cli from 7 to 8 with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to upgrade your typescript version to 3.7 on your Ubuntu machine. From [typescript 3.7 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html):

> To detect the issue around accessors, TypeScript 3.7 will now emit
>   get/set accessors in .d.ts files so that in TypeScript can check for
>   overridden accessors. so presumably sequelize was compiled with
>   typescript 3.7 and emits definition files that previous versions don't
>   understand. So you'll need to upgrade to typescript 3.7 or use an
>   earlier version of sequelize.